# 403 Forbidden nginx (nginx/1.8.0)

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-403, forbidden

I've just got a new server in DigitalOcean and want to try some other things. I want to start a wordpress site so I follow the first 1-3 steps from here: https://deliciousbrains.com/hosting-wordpress-yourself-nginx-php-mysql/. At first everything goes well and I did managed to get the wordpress installed. Unfortunately I am currently having 403 Forbidden on my site.

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 x64. I already stuck for quite sometimes and still have no ideas on whats going on. I even tried to remove the Nginx and reinstall, still the same.

Here is my conf file:

```
user sylvia;
worker_processes 1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 15;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;
        client_max_body_size 64m;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 2;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

       server {
              listen 80 default_server;
               server_name _;
               return 444;
                    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Look at your error logs.

Comment: Please add your virtual host (server) nginx config, as well as the content of nginx  error log...

Comment: Do you have any security modules active?
I know apache's mod_security2 can throw 403's happily on every page when misconfigured.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it is a permission issue.
Give permission to  www-data user to access your web root directory.
Aur you can also give ownership.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Forbidden means NGINX is not able to open the directory in which the files are stored.

The NGINX error_logs will give you the exact cause for the problem.

The logs are stored in /var/logs/nginx/error_log. Just open the file and go the the last lines and see what exact error your'e getting.

Ideally, doing a chmod 755 directory will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the a 403 problem as well, which was caused by the mode of directory.

I set the root directory under home,and the default mode for home directory is 600.

Then I found this article https://gist.github.com/jhjguxin/6208474 , and tried to change the root directory to 755, and the problem was solved.

> So it seems that the default permissions on user home directories in
>   Ubuntu 12.04 is 700.** Nginx needs to have read permission the files
>   that should be served AND have execute permission in each of the
>   parent directories along the path from the root to the served files.**
>
> You can give your user directory these permissions by running
>
> chmod 701 user_home
>
> You may also use 755, which is the default
>   permission setting on the home directory on many systems.
>
> The directories/files in your web root can belong to the www-data user
>   or your regular personal user as long as the user/group that nginx
>   runs as (as defined in nginx.conf) has READ permission on all files to
>   be served and execute permission on all web root directories.

Comment: Adding info from the link would improve your answer

Answer (score 0):

This case is occur when you run Mamp with the Server Nginx and nginx server needed configuration of each working folder/directory. 
for the nginx configuration you can go in nginx.conf file on path

> C:\MAMP\conf\nginx\nginx.conf

and write this script.

```
http {
    .....
    server {


    location ~* /test(.*)$ {
    root             C:/MAMP/htdocs/test;
        index            index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files        $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass     127.0.0.1:9100;
            fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include          fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

  }
}
```

note: in this script **test** is my working directory. you can replace this name.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to list directory contents use `autoindex on;` like:

```
location /somedir {
       autoindex on;
}
```